# NmeaListener in IntentService does not work

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have used NmeaListener in an Intent Service.

The problem - onNmeaReceived is never getting called.

```
//This is a reference code 

 public class NMEAService extends IntentService {

   private static NMEAListener listener;

   // This function would be called from onHandleIntent
    protected void getNMEA() {
    listener = new NMEAListener();
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0,        
    listener,Looper.myLooper());
    lm.addNmeaListener(listener);
   }


  private class NMEAListener implements NmeaListener{

     @Override
     public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
        // NMEA Received
        // This is never getting called
        }

     @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // This is getting called
      }

     @Override
     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }


      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are never calling your `getNMEA()` method.

Second, your code does not compile, as your `@Override` annotations on methods like `onLocationChanged()` will fail, as you are not overriding anything.

Third, an `IntentService` goes away once `onHandleIntent()` returns. Android will terminate your process sometime after that, taking your listener with it. Never register a listener from an `IntentService`. Use a regular `Service`.

Fourth, `addNmeaListener()` [would appear to be unreliable](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15500), working on some devices but not others. I would try to find some known-to-be-working NMEA code and try that, to see whether your device should work with it.

Comment: Thanks Commonsware , This is just a reference code not the complete code. In my actual code, I have called getNMEA() and put Logs in onLocationChanged() and I can see the logs from onLocationChanged.

Comment: Comment on your third point - Using IntentService , If I do use requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, PendingIntent intent) , then also It works fine , Only issue is with NmeaListener.

Comment: @GOLI: That's because the `PendingIntent` approach does not require your process to stick around. A listener does. Never register a listener from an `IntentService`.